# How do I create a fragment view without the layout inflater?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am working on `Fragments` in `Android` and would like to programmatically inflate my view - without the `LayoutInflater`. In my `class`, which `extends Fragment`, I would like to do something basic, like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return new View(inflater.getContext());
}
```

However in my `FragmentActivity` with this onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

and this `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <fragment class="edu.self.myFragment" 
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:tag="foo"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting an error with the layout:

```
11-11 23:25:18.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #12: Duplicate id 0x7f050000, tag foo, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for edu.self.myFragment
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: @Raghunandan. Broken link

Comment: @Binghammer mods have deleted the question. hence the broken link

Answer (score -1):

You can't inflate an xml containing a fragment inside another fragment.  You have to add the sub-fragment manually.